# Ubuntu Server 20.04.4, random disconnects from LAN, reboot hangs

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

Ubuntu Server 20.04.4, randomly disconnects from LAN, after disconnects, most of the time, all network related commands will result in a 'hang', meaning no error messages, just a blank line after command. Only way out after that is a hold power button reboot, because even Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't work properly, it just takes forever to run through a bunch of steps, always hang up on closing something, I waited for 5 mins and tried forcibly reboot, still not rebooting, as showing in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etWjc.jpg).

I say most of the time, because just now I ran into a disconnect but was able to run network commands without any issues, in this case, it seems ethernet is connected [ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wkGy.png), but when pinging gateway or any other computer on the network, I got **Destination host unreachable**.

Also this is the error message I saw in console when the first type of crash happens, not sure if it's helpful:
[Error message on the console after ethernet disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOHbW.png)

**Edit**: I'm running Ubuntu Server on my Surface Pro 4 laptop, and connecting to ethernet with an usb-to-ethernet adapter, wireless is disabled.

**Edit**: I have already tried all the solutions I can find online for similar problems including disabling power management on usb ports, restarting network services, checking for firmware upgrades etc.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Server on my Surface Pro 4 laptop, and connecting to ethernet with an usb-to-ethernet adapter, wireless is disabled. Is this what you mean by setup?

Comment: The message says docker there is not mention of docker in the question.

Comment: I have Home Assistant, Portainer, Omada Controller installed in docker, I just didn't think that's related.

Comment: any ideas @David?